# Getting Error while using Imgproc.rectangle in netbeans fusing OpenCV3 for face detection?

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans, face-detection, opencv3.0

On using the following code:-

```
Imgproc.rectangle(frame, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
```

in netbeans 8 for face detection using OpenCV 3 I am having trouble in drawing a rectangle in  Mat frame.

Netbeans says:-

> incompatible type:cannot convert java.awt.point to
>   org.opencv.core.point

I need help its for my Project can anybody solve it.......???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Near the top of your file, change:

```
import java.awt.Point;
```

to

```
import org.opencv.core.Point;
```

If you use the Fix Imports feature, be sure to carefully check the dialog and select the right package when it is importing a class found in multiple packages.